# Connection to AD works fine in IIS but not in VS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, active-directory

I'm using the following code to check if an username exist in an AD, when i debug the app in VS it throws "The username or password is incorrect" exception but if I publish the exact same code in IIS it works fine, returning true or false as expected

```
private bool UserExist(string path, string username)
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path);
            try
            {
                object obj = entry.NativeObject;
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                if (null == result)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: And what credentials is the IIS app pool running under? Does it have more access to AD than your account does? And what's the point of `obj`? I don't see it used anywhere in your code.

Comment: In the iis is running under the default "ApplicationPoolIdentity", and the obj yes it doesn't do anything, if i remove the line still throws the exception, actually I'm connecting to two ADs and one works fine in both IIS and VS but the other one doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can mean that the credentials used to access the domain are not trusted on the domain.

When ApplicationPoolIdentity is used, it authenticates as the computer. So as long as the domain of that computer is trusted in both domains, then it will work on both domains.

When you debug in Visual Studio using IIS Express, it's running under your own credentials. If it works for one domain and not the other, then that means that your user account is not trusted on the one domain.

You have two options:

1. Change your code to pass proper credentials in the constructor of `DirectoryEntry`, depending on the domain you need to connect to, or
2. If your computer is on the same domain as the computer you say it works on, then install full IIS on your computer (not IIS Express), setup the site in IIS, and [setup Visual Studio to debug the app in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2019#debug-aspnet-apps). This way, it won't run under your credentials when debugging.

Comment: My credentials belong to the AD that isn't working on VS, and recently my user was changed from "myname.ext" to just "myname" but in the development server the user still is "myname.ext", you think that has something to do with it?  because before the user change i was able to connect to both domains from VS

Comment: Your username was changed (what you use to login to your computer)? Have you logged out since it was changed?

Comment: To login to the development server i use just "myname" but in the task manager the user still appears as "myname.ext", i haven't  logged out

Comment: You can try specifically logging out, not just disconnecting. (I assume you're using Remote Desktop?)